# How to get a Provider value in my Flutter view using Provider?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building a flutter app  following on from the pattern described in [this tutorial](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-provider-v3-architecture-using-proxyprovider-for-injection-62cf5c58ea52) using MultiProvider from Provider (3.1.0).

In my home page I want to load config data (venue currency symbol) but not display the model. I have used a pattern similar to the login service in the tutorial linked above but when I try to use the value `Provider.of<Venue>(context).currency` in another view (bills) I get this error.

> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building
>   BillListItem(dirty, dependencies: [InheritedProvider]): The
>   getter 'currency' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling:
>   currency

I can't figure out what is different from the login where I can get Provider.of<  User>(context).name

Here is my code:

main.dart

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: providers,
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        initialRoute: RoutePaths.Login,
        onGenerateRoute: Router.generateRoute,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The view where I want to consume the provider value.

```
class BillListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final Bill bill;
  final Function onTap;

  const BillListItem({this.bill, this.onTap});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 15.0),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                  blurRadius: 3.0,
                  offset: Offset(0.0, 2.0),
                  color: Color.fromARGB(80, 0, 0, 0))
            ]),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(bill.billNumber.toString(), style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w900, fontSize: 16.0),),

            Text("${Provider.of<Venue>(context).currency}${bill.payable.toString()}", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w900, fontSize: 16.0),),     
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }  
}
```

The tab view where I inject the venue:

```
class TabContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => TabContainerState();
}

class TabContainerState extends State<TabContainer> {
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _fetchVenue(context));
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return BaseWidget<VenueModel>(
      model: VenueModel(venueService: Provider.of(context)),
      builder: (context, model, child) => DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,       
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              isScrollable: false,
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.home)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.room_service)),
              ],
            ), 
          centerTitle : true,
          title: Text('Exact POS'),
          actions: <Widget>[
             FutureBuilder<String>(
                future: SharedPreferencesHelper.getLanguageCode(),
                initialData: 'en',
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
                    return snapshot.hasData
                    ? BuildFlag.buildFlag(context, snapshot.data)
                    : Container();
                }
             ),
          ]
        ),

        body: SafeArea(
          child: TabBarView(
            children: [
              HomeView(),
              LoginView(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
       )
      )
    );
  }
   void _fetchVenue(BuildContext context) async {
     Api _api = new Api();
     VenueService _venueService = new VenueService(api: _api);
     VenueModel _venueModel = new VenueModel(venueService: _venueService); 
     var success = await _venueModel.fetchVenue();
  } 
}
```

`home_view.dart`. I suspect that this may be where I need to inject the `Venue` provider instead of in `TabContainer`.

```
class HomeView extends StatefulWidget{

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => HomeViewState();
}

class HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => showSnackBar());
  }

  void showSnackBar(){
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                content: Text('Welcome ${Provider.of<User>(context).name}',    
                              style: snackBarStyle), 
                backgroundColor: snackBarColor,
                duration: Duration(seconds: 4),
      ));
  }

  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return SafeArea(
               child: Scaffold(
                       backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
                       body: Column(
                               crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                               children: <Widget>[
                                  UIHelper.verticalSpaceSmall,
                                  Expanded(
                                     child: Tables(),)
                               ],
                       ),
             )
    );

  }  
}
```

My view model `VenueModel`

```
class VenueModel extends BaseModel {
  VenueService _venueService;

  VenueModel(
      {@required VenueService venueService,}
  ) : _venueService = venueService;

  Future<bool> fetchVenue() async {
    setBusy(true);
    var success = await _venueService.fetchVenue();
    setBusy(false);
    return success;
  }
}
```

My service `VenueService`

```
class VenueService {
  final Api _api;
  VenueService({Api api}) : _api = api;

  StreamController<Venue> _venueController = StreamController<Venue>();
  Stream<Venue> get venue => _venueController.stream;

  Future<bool> fetchVenue() async {
    var fetchedVenue = await _api.getVenue();
    var hasVenue = fetchedVenue != null;
    if (hasVenue) {
      _venueController.add(fetchedVenue);
    }
    return hasVenue;
  }
}
```

My `BaseModel.dart`

```
class BaseModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _busy = false;
  bool get busy => _busy;

  void setBusy(bool value) {
    _busy = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

My Provider setup code:

```
List<SingleChildCloneableWidget> providers = [
  ...independentServices,
  ...dependentServices,
  ...uiConsumableProviders
];

List<SingleChildCloneableWidget> independentServices = [ 
  Provider.value(value: Api())
];

List<SingleChildCloneableWidget> dependentServices = [
  ProxyProvider<Api, AuthenticationService>(
    builder: (context, api, authenticationService) => AuthenticationService(api: api),
  ),

  ProxyProvider<Api, VenueService>(
    builder: (context, api, venueService) => VenueService(api: api),
  ),
];

List<SingleChildCloneableWidget> uiConsumableProviders = [

  StreamProvider<User>(
    builder: (context) => Provider.of<AuthenticationService>(context, listen: false).user,  
  ),

    StreamProvider<Venue>(
    builder: (context) => Provider.of<VenueService>(context, listen: false).venue,
  ),
];
```

base_widget.dart

```
class BaseWidget<T extends ChangeNotifier> extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget Function(BuildContext context, T model, Widget child) builder;
  final T model;
  final Widget child;
  final Function(T) onModelReady;

  BaseWidget({
    Key key,
    this.builder,
    this.model,
    this.child,
    this.onModelReady,
  }) : super(key: key);

  _BaseWidgetState<T> createState() => _BaseWidgetState<T>();
}

class _BaseWidgetState<T extends ChangeNotifier> extends State<BaseWidget<T>> {
  T model;

  @override
  void initState() {
    model = widget.model;

    if (widget.onModelReady != null) {
      widget.onModelReady(model);
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<T>(
      builder: (context) => model,
      child: Consumer<T>(
        builder: widget.builder,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your `MultiProvider`?

Comment: I edited my answer to include `main.dart` which has the `MutiProvider`

Comment: where is your BillListItem used?Providers based on InheritedWidget,So you must confirm BillListItem is TabContainer child element

Comment: and where is your VenueModel used？Has it been created only once?For example, Is your HomeView has this code `VenueModel(venueService: Provider.of(context))`,

Comment: Yes, you can see it in the code above titled home view.

Comment: How can I make `BillListItem` a parent of `TabContainer`?

Comment: sorry, I mean a child of 'TabContainer'?

Comment: @markhorrocks for example,BillListItem is child of ListView, and ListView is child of HomeView,then the BillListItem is child of TabContainer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202774/discussion-between-lucky-dog-and-markhorrocks).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building
>   BillListItem(dirty, dependencies: [InheritedProvider]): The getter
>   'currency' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: currency

This errors means that `Provider.of<Venue>(context)` is returning `null`. This could be due to 2 reasons:

1. `null` values are added to the stream in `VenueService`. Which is not the case given your code, which leads me to believe it is the 2nd reason:
2. There are no values emitted by the stream in `VenueService`, so the initial data of the stream is `null`

After looking through your code, the only time you've called `fetchVenue` in the `VenueService` is in your tab view:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _fetchVenue(context));
```

```
void _fetchVenue(BuildContext context) async {
  Api _api = new Api();
  VenueService _venueService = new VenueService(api: _api);
  VenueModel _venueModel = new VenueModel(venueService: _venueService); 
  var success = await _venueModel.fetchVenue();
}
```

In your `_fetchVenue` function, you're actually creating new instances of `Api`, `VenueService` and `VenueModel` which do not get used anywhere else in the app. The actual `VenueService` in the providers list is left untouched. The `fetchVenue` function in the actual `VenueService` never gets called, and this is why the `Provider.of<Venue>(context)` returns `null`, because the stream has no values.

So you can replace your `_fetchVenue` function with this:

```
void _fetchVenue(BuildContext context) async {
  VenueService _venueService = Provider.of(context);
  VenueModel _venueModel = new VenueModel(venueService: _venueService); 
  var success = await _venueModel.fetchVenue();
}
```

There are still some improvements needed to be made, like the fact that `_venueModel` is not used anywhere, but I hope that this solves your problem!

Comment: Thank you. I think I will also move it to run it before main. I managed just now to get provider working with a custom version of this tutorial. https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-internationalization-the-easy-way-using-provider-and-json-c47caa4212b2